# Bash script with quotes and spaces

Tags: bash, shell, git, quoting

I'm trying to get some nice output out of git:

```
FORMAT='%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'
LOG_PARAMS="--color --pretty=format:$FORMAT --abbrev-commit --no-walk"
function gch() {
  git log $LOG_PARAMS $(commits)
}
```

(where commits is a function that collects relevant commits). But I get this instead:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '%(s)': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Presumably that has something to do with the quoting and spaces, but I'm far from fluent in bash. Any help?

Comment: The `function` prefix is a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism), and can be removed without changing anything.

Comment: useful tip. I'd give your answer an upvote, too, but I don't have enough karma :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just suffered from [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) - [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting) and use arrays if you want to send multiple parameters to a command:

```
LOG_PARAMS=("--color" "--pretty=format:$FORMAT" "--abbrev-commit" "--no-walk")
...
    git log "${LOG_PARAMS[@]}" "$(commits)"
```

This works for me without the `"$(commits)"` part, which I guess is another function you created.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't quite work. If I run `git log "$LOG_PARAMS"` I get `fatal: unrecognized argument: --color --pretty=format:%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset --abbrev-commit --no-walk`. Is this because git is so 'special'?

Comment: Umm, sorry, didn't quite read that properly. I'll correct it.

Comment: Excellent, that worked! Thank you very much!